# How do I group pandas Dataframe columns into MultiIndex (row or column wise)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a DataFrame which is read (`pd.read_csv`) from a file (a very messy file).

I'm trying to clean it up in a way that I can easily plot graphs afterwards with *Plotly* Express or use it for other purposes such as means calculations.

I already cleaned it a bit so I have a time index (`pd.date_range`). Each column can be grouped by trios and is repeated for each site (Contamination, Temperature and Depth). I'd like to extract from the column name the site number (*because site number `IS NOT` continuous*) and use it to multiindex my *DataFrame* (or something similar).

**Here is a example of my DataFrame structure (real site number goes up to 600 ans is not continous):**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start="2021-01", periods=12, freq='M'), data={"Site_101_Contamination":np.random.rand(12),"Site_101_Temperature":np.random.rand(12),"Site_101_Depth":np.random.rand(12),"Site_102_Contamination":np.random.rand(12),"Site_102_Temperature":np.random.rand(12),"Site_102_Depth":np.random.rand(12),"Site_103_Contamination":np.random.rand(12),"Site_103_Temperature":np.random.rand(12),"Site_103_Depth":np.random.rand(12),"Site_104_Contamination":np.random.rand(12),"Site_104_Temperature":np.random.rand(12),"Site_104_Depth":np.random.rand(12)})
df
```

**My question is threefold:**

1- How do I create this *MultiIndexed DataFrame* with 2 row indexes (first level: date; and second level: site number) with a resulting 3 columns *DataFrame* (Contamination, Temperature, Depth)? Also, should I also add names to indexes (date, site_no) - how do I do that?

e.g. What I want the final DataFrame to look like for Question 1:

|  |  | Contamination | Temperature | Depth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **date** | **site_no** |  |  |  |
| 2021-01 | 101 | 2.3423511 | 15.2345511 | 32.32556 |
|  | ... | ... | ... | ... |
|  | 614 | 325.25560 | -5.23500120 | 252.0395 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-12 | 101 | 2.3112394 | 19.2038412 | 39.23189 |
|  | ... | ... | ... | ... |
|  | 614 | 305.56779 | -2.6798520 | 211.7794 |

2- How do I create this *MultiIndexed DataFrame* with 1 row index (date), but with 2 indexes on columns (first level: [insert site number], second level: Contamination, Temperature, Depth)?

e.g. What I want the final DataFrame to look like for Question 2:

|  | 101 | (101, inferred) | (101, inferred) | ... | 614 | (614, inferred) | (614, inferred) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **Contamination** | **Temperature** | **Depth** | ... | **Contamination** | **Temperature** | **Depth** |
| **date** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2021-01 | 2.3423511 | 15.2345511 | 32.32556 | ... | 325.25560 | -5.23500120 | 252.0395 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |  |
| 2021-12 | 2.3112394 | 19.2038412 | 39.23189 | ... | 614 | 305.56779 | -2.6798520 |

3- Which of these *MultiIndexed DataFrame* is more pythonic or 'best-practice' and why?

Bonus question:

4- If your answer is not of intermediate level, is it possible to add information (or links) as to how to access values, columns or rows with this MultiIndex?

__

Comment: Dont use `...` when giving an example. just give values. The easiest way to share data is to run `df.head(5).to_dct()` copy that and paste

Comment: I added my DataFrame as example in the code section above.
Thanks for the info though, I'll use it for non-confidential data ;)

Comment: I have provided the answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
df.stack().unstack([1,2])

site_no           101                                 614                      
        Contamination Temperature     Depth Contamination Temperature     Depth
date                                                                           
2021-01      2.342351   15.234551  32.32556     325.25560   -5.235001  252.0395
2021-12      2.311239   19.203841  39.23189     305.56779   -2.679852  211.7794
```

---

Edit

With the new data:

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index()
df1[['site_no', 'Type']] = df1['level_1'].str.split('(?<=\\d)_', expand = True)

df1.pivot('level_0', ['site_no', 'Type'], 0)


site_no         Site_101              ...    Site_104          
Type       Contamination Temperature  ... Temperature     Depth
level_0                               ...                      
2021-01-31      0.379259    0.419999  ...    0.907264  0.325225
2021-02-28      0.974815    0.305933  ...    0.529651  0.850517
2021-03-31      0.761665    0.431613  ...    0.525826  0.282361
2021-04-30      0.675198    0.455258  ...    0.273308  0.921283
2021-05-31      0.054640    0.379733  ...    0.425278  0.400155
2021-06-30      0.467902    0.863513  ...    0.293179  0.335472
2021-07-31      0.146240    0.052324  ...    0.925729  0.910898
2021-08-31      0.076072    0.347316  ...    0.130894  0.517572
2021-09-30      0.470561    0.530088  ...    0.245784  0.019819
2021-10-31      0.314711    0.611415  ...    0.130266  0.498167
2021-11-30      0.493516    0.627174  ...    0.846266  0.389009
2021-12-31      0.256572    0.309157  ...    0.860257  0.107073
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Here :

pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start="2021-01", periods=12, freq='M'), data={"Site_101_Contamination":np.random.rand(12),"Site_101_Temperature":np.random.rand(12),"Site_101_Depth":np.random.rand(12),"Site_102_Contamination":np.random.rand(12),"Site_102_Temperature":np.random.rand(12),"Site_102_Depth":np.random.rand(12),"Site_103_Contamination":np.random.rand(12),"Site_103_Temperature":np.random.rand(12),"Site_103_Depth":np.random.rand(12),"Site_104_Contamination":np.random.rand(12),"Site_104_Temperature":np.random.rand(12),"Site_104_Depth":np.random.rand(12)})

Comment: @PythonicQuestions so you do have multiple columns. I did not know that

Comment: @PythonicQuestions check the edit

Comment: This does work and answers part of my question! Thanks!